# Keep reference of original points in a convex_hull_3

Tags: computational-geometry, cgal

I would like to now if there is any mechanism to keep a reference on original vertices when computing a convex_hull_3 with CGAL or maybe something similar than CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2 in order to compute convex_hull_3 for points with additional informations.
thanks!

Comment: The simplest option I see is to use the class `Delaunay_triangulation_3` with info in the vertices and use the simplices incident to the infinite vertex.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but I think it came at the price of a loss of performance ?

Comment: You're right. Another solution is to provide you own traits class, with point being indices. It is not hard but requires some care.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. I will follow this way, it seems the most rewarding.

Comment: If successful, do not hesitate to contribute your solution upstream as it may be useful to other!

Comment: For sure!. for now,  I begun to implement my own Convex_hull_traits_3<K, Has_filtered_predicates_tag> class with std::pair<K::Point_3, size_t> as a type of point but at the end it seems I have to change too much things (for example I think I must also create some Polyhedron traits class etc...) maybe I haven't made the good choice. Could you maybe confirm or infirm that ? thanks.

Comment: You indeed need to modified the Polyhedron traits so that your point type is taken into account. About the CH traits, you simply need to forward the operator() calls of each functor to the regular traits class. If you have 2D degenerate cases, you'll also need to override `Traits_xy`, `Traits_yz` and `Traits_xz`. The concept documentation page is [here](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/classConvexHullTraits__3.html). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. yes, the CH trait implementation is straightforward. I end up with the kind of thing you describe. but the polyhedron thing seems more complicated or intricated.

Comment: Ok, my bad, maybe I just need to follow this http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polyhedron/index.html#PolyhedronExtending

Comment: Copy-paste `Polyhedron_items_3` and change the point type.